# Keyboard Winforms on Windows 10 (surface)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, touch

i have my WinForms Application running on a Surface Pro with Windows 10 in Tablet Mode.
No Physical Keyboard attached.

I launch my Application and when I hit a TextBox the touch keyboard does not appear. (Its a simple Windows.Forms.TextBox Control) With my custom Control that inherits from the TextBox it does not work as well.

When I "click" in a ComboBox the touch keyboard comes to the front. It also appears when I click in my custom ComboBox that inherits from Windows.Forms.ComboBox.

When I click to a TextBox after I clicked a ComboBox the opened touch keyboard closes.

How can I solve my problem? is there a c# command I can add to the control in order to force the apparition of the touch keyboard?

I already changed the setting "Show the touch keyboard or handwriting panel when not in tablet mode and there's no keyboard attached" to "On", because I read that in another thread, but nothing changed.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following code in the event handler:

```
var progFiles = @"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink";
var keyboardPath = Path.Combine(progFiles, "TabTip.exe");

this.keyboardProc = Process.Start(keyboardPath);
```

What we are doing there, is manually launching the Touch Keyboard.

This should work, however you may have a problem dismissing the keyboard automatically after the textbox lost its focus.

By the way, did you check the following option is enabled?

[image]

Comment: I´m going to try your solution. 
+The option you mentioned is enabled.

Comment: @dertrautmann Great, let me know how it goes. If it does not work for whatever reason, I can research more and change the answer.

Comment: @Alex would you please please tell me why I do not have the option you highlighted inside the red rectangle? I just finished installing the latest update and I can't see this option. Instead, I have "Show the touch keyboard or handwriting panel when not in tablet mode and theres no keyboard attached"

Comment: @ToniAz have you tried toggling between Tablet/Desktop mode?

Comment: @Alex tried pretty much everything. I used get the keyboard pop up in all text fields, no problem. But a week ago I noticed it wasn't popping up in Google Chrome text fields. It does pop up in OS text boxes though.

Comment: @ToniAz As far as I know this is a Chrome issue as described here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=491516.

One of the solutions (I have not tried this): "Clone the desktop shortcut for Chrome you're using
Open its properties
In object field, right after "C:\chrome location" write space and this: --disable-usb-keyboard-detect

Comment: Hey Alex, remember to "Process.GetProcessesByName("TabTip")(0).Kill()" beforehand, since only the first-run actually spawns the keyboard. After that it lingers in the background supressing future tabtip.exe's from running.